# Spring Boot + Cloud | Zuul Filter threw Exception

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I've been working on my first microservice app using spring boot and I can't figure out whats wrong with my configurations.

I created 3 microservices, the discovery server (eureka), the edge server (zuul) and another one with REST services.
I start the discovery and the edge server, and then I start the core service, but when I try any rest url, the edge server throws a "**Filter threw Exception**" and "**org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaRibbonClientConfiguration'**"

This is my configuration:

**Discovery Server:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class InMenuDiscoveryService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InMenuDiscoveryService.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 1111   # HTTP (Tomcat) port

# Configure this Discovery Server
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    #preferIpAddress: true
  client:  # Not a client, don't register with yourself
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  serviceUrl:
        defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Angel.SR6</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Edge-Server:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
@EnableZuulProxy
public class EdgeServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(EdgeServerApplication.class).web(true).run(args);
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
info:
  component: Edge Server

spring:
  application:
     name: edge-server

# HTTP Server
server:
  port: 3333

# Discovery Server Access
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:1111/eureka/
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true

endpoints:
  restart:
    enabled: true
  shutdown:
    enabled: true
  health:
    sensitive: false
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <springcloud.version>1.0.6.RELEASE</springcloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        <version>${springcloud.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${springcloud.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springcloud.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
        <version>${springcloud.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**REST-client**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class CoreServiceApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(CoreServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.application.name=core-service

# Discovery Server Access
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:1111/eureka/
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true

server.port=2222
management.port=2221
management.address=127.0.0.1
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <springframework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <springcloud.version>1.0.6.RELEASE</springcloud.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.0.7.Final</hibernate.version>
    <jackson.version>2.6.5</jackson.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${springcloud.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springcloud.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        <version>${springcloud.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-rev-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**RestCotroller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/branch")
public class BranchRESTService
{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<BranchDTO> getRestaurantBranches()
    {
        BranchDTO branch = new BranchDTO();
        branch.setId(1);
        branch.setBranchName("saraza");
        branch.setDelivers(true);
        return new ResponseEntity<BranchDTO>(branch, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And this is what the edge server throws when I try to reach the rest service "http://localhost:3333/core-service/branch/all"

```
--- [pool-5-thread-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : Mapped URL path [/edge-server/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController]
--- [pool-5-thread-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : Mapped URL path [/core-service/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController]
--- [  XNIO-2 task-1] io.undertow.servlet                      : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
--- [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
--- [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 60 ms
--- [  XNIO-2 task-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.filters.ProxyRouteLocator   : Finding route for path: /core-service/branch/all
--- [  XNIO-2 task-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@63a9b2f6: startup date [Sat Feb 13 17:56:38 UYT 2016]; parent: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@39de3d36
--- [  XNIO-2 task-1] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
--- [  XNIO-2 task-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaRibbonClientConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken
--- [  XNIO-2 task-1] com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet        : Filter threw Exception

com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Filter threw Exception
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:231) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:120) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:84) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:111) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:77) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:158) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequestInternal(ZuulController.java:43) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.0.7.RELEASE.jar:1.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:237) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) [undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174) [undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202) [undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793) [undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar:1.3.14.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaRibbonClientConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.createContext(SpringClientFactory.java:148) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.0.7.RELEASE.jar:1.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getContext(SpringClientFactory.java:113) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.0.7.RELEASE.jar:1.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getInstance(SpringClientFactory.java:181) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.0.7.RELEASE.jar:1.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getClient(SpringClientFactory.java:82) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.0.7.RELEASE.jar:1.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:96) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.0.7.RELEASE.jar:1.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:na]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken
    at com.netflix.client.config.CommonClientConfigKey.<init>(CommonClientConfigKey.java:251) ~[ribbon-core-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at com.netflix.client.config.CommonClientConfigKey$1.<init>(CommonClientConfigKey.java:33) ~[ribbon-core-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at com.netflix.client.config.CommonClientConfigKey.<clinit>(CommonClientConfigKey.java:33) ~[ribbon-core-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.EurekaRibbonClientConfiguration.preprocess(EurekaRibbonClientConfiguration.java:129) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.0.7.RELEASE.jar:1.0.7.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 86 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    ... 97 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 137
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like guava is missing.

Comment: Thanks, that was one issue, the other issue was that spring boot was downloading different versions of ribbon. All ribbon libraries were in 2.0.0 version with the exception of ribbon-httpclient, that was on 2.0-RC9, so I added the 2.0.0 version to match the other libraries and the error disapeared.