# Intermittent com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Filter threw Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I am using spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul-2.2.9.RELEASE apigateway for routing the service urls (calling from reactjs UI) and facing intermittent API failures,

I tried to understand the issue but couldnt find root cause and solution to mitigate the issue.

This issue happening once in a while and not everytime and Also observed, failures happening for specific apis only.
I need the apigateway for only routing purpose,

Please help for any better solution

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Filter threw Exception
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:227)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.postRoute(FilterProcessor.java:92)
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.postRoute(ZuulRunner.java:87)
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.postRoute(ZuulServlet.java:107)
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:166)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:45)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.dbs.itt.oapm.agent.web.servlet.filter.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.instrument.web.LazyTracingFilter.doFilter(TraceWebServletConfiguration.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: null
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.rethrowRuntimeException(ReflectionUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendResponseFilter.run(SendResponseFilter.java:115)
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:783)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendResponseFilter.writeResponse(SendResponseFilter.java:260)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendResponseFilter.writeResponse(SendResponseFilter.java:162)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendResponseFilter.run(SendResponseFilter.java:112)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:79)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:466)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:135)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:151)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1367)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:766)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:586)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:530)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:546)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:112)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:193)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:340)
    ... 70 common frames omitted
```

Spring boot version
spring-boot-starter-parent 2.4.6
zuul dependancy:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

route sample from application.yml

```
zuul:
  routes:
    backend-service:
      url: http://localhost:10011
```

tried adding as below

```
zuul
  retryable: true
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 20000
    socket-timeout-millis: 60000

hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 1100
ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 1000
  ReadTimeout: 1000
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35385752/3303074)

Comment: I have gone thru this before,  but that's not relevant, Here i am able to route to service API URLs and got the response, but Its the issue not able to return to client. Thanks